# OpenShift 3.x. Access internal registry with a token that does not expire

Tags: openshift

When I need to access to openshift internal registry I do:

```
docker login -u admin -p $(oc whoami -t) docker-registry-default.mycluster.com
```

But this token expire so I can not use `admin/"token"` to create a secret.

If I want to configure an `imagePullSecrets` inside a Pod to get an image from other namespace I do not know how to create that secret with a token that does not expire.

Any hit?

Thank you.

Comment: That's the use case of a service account: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/service_accounts.html

Comment: Ok, imagine I need an imagePullSecret, how could I create it with a token that does not expire

Comment: That's what a service account token is for, they don't expire and they're significantly longer (considered more secure)

Comment: See https://cookbook.openshift.org/accessing-an-openshift-cluster/how-can-i-create-a-service-account-for-scripted-access.html

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton great URL. Thx!

Comment: @WillGordon thx, now I understand your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by Graham, the solution is described in: https://cookbook.openshift.org/accessing-an-openshift-cluster/how-can-i-create-a-service-account-for-scripted-access.html

```
oc project default
oc create sa robot


Give privileges to the service account to access to the repository:

Correct way to do it:
    oc policy add-role-to-user system:image-puller system:serviceaccount:project-a:default --namespace=project-b
    After adding that role, the pods in project-a that reference the default service account is able to pull images from project-b.

Quick and dirty:

oc policy add-role-to-user cluster-admin system:serviceaccount:default:robot



oc describe sa robot
...
Image pull secrets:  robot-dockercfg-s9v9x
...


oc describe secret robot-dockercfg-s9v9x

apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockercfg: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
...
...

Decode .dockercfg value from base64

...
"docker-registry.default.svc:5000":{
      "username":"serviceaccount",
      "password":"PasswordValue",
      "email":"serviceaccount@example.org",
      "auth":"yyyyy"
   }
...

docker login -u serviceaccount -p PasswordValue docker-registry-default.myclusterdomain.com
```